# Biometric Auth in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In IOS is ok. FaceId is working. But in Android, the fingerprint is don't work.
Error: I/flutter (19430): [BiometricType.fingerprint]
I/flutter (19430): PlatformException(no_fragment_activity, local_auth plugin requires activity to be a FragmentActivity., null). My code doesn't have MainActivity.java. Is embedding below

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="io.flutter.examples.test">

    <!-- The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
         flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC"/>

    <application android:label="AY">
        <activity android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
                  android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
   <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
        This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
```

if you have java code

```
package yourpackagename;

import android.os.Bundle;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
  }
}
```

if  you have kotlin code

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    }
}
```